# Google Webmaster Tools Site Not Indexing

Tags: indexing, seo, google-search-console, bing-webmaster-tools

I am trying to submit my site http://jobmigo.com to Google but after 3 weeks it has not been indexed. Possible problems are one I only have two urls to submit as this is a password protected site, but these urls have a lot of content on them. Two this is an angular based website, so I use prerender to cache pages with rendered content for Google. Third the index.jsp redirects to the home page, this might also bea problem. Which of these are most likely causing the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow">
```

on http://jobmigo.com/jobs-admin/index?origin=landing basically tells google not to index your page.. So that might be the main issue here.

Answer (score 0):

All the pages I looked at had a noindex tag on.

Comment: not sure how I missed that, i removed it and will see if it helps